# pointPlacement in Highcharts Heatmap with datetime xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

How can I achieve to display my hourly sampled data in the hour after its timestamp (and not centered on it). I do not want to manipulate the data.

*A timestamp at 00:00 should show the data between the ticks 00:00 and 01:00*

After reading the documentation I tried to achieve this with pointPlacement in combination with pointRange.

In the following example I would like to see the data **between** the ticks at 1,2 and 3 hours. The options of pointPlacement do not change the visualization as expected, as can be seen in the following fiddle.

Do I misunderstand pointPlacement or did I miss any preconditions?

Any other ideas how to fix the dataplacement here?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1pkLe0o/7/)

**HTML** and **JS** :

```js
var hour = 60 * 60 * 1000;

var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 80,
    plotBorderWidth: 1
  },


  title: {
    text: 'Test pointPlacement in heatmap with datetime axis'
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime"
  },

  yAxis: {
    categories: ['Cat 0', 'Cat 1'],
    title: null
  },

  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'vertical',
    margin: 0,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 25,
    symbolHeight: 280
  },

  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return '<b>' + '</b> Color Axis: <b>' +
        this.point.value + '</b><br> y-Axis: <b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'hourly values of category',
    colsize: hour,
    pointRange: hour,
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [
      [hour, 0, 1],
      [2 * hour, 0, 2],
      [hour, 1, 3],
      [2 * hour, 1, 4]
    ],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      color: '#000000'
    }
  }]

});

function placement(option) {
  chart.setTitle({
    text: "Placement Option: " + String(option)
  })

  chart.series[0].update({
    pointPlacement: option
  }, true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<button onclick='placement(null);'>
    null
</button>

<button onclick='placement("on");'>
    on
</button>

<button onclick='placement("between");'>
    between
</button>

<button onclick='placement(-0.5);'>
    -0.5
</button>
    
<button onclick='placement(0.5);'>
    0.5
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that numeric values of `pointPlacement` doesn't work in heatmap (I reported it on github): https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7860

**Workaround:**

You can manually change the position of the ticks (`tickPositioner`) and print the original value to the user (`labels.formatter`).

```
  xAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function() {
      // manually apply offset to all ticks
      this.tickPositions = this.tickPositions.map(x => x - offset);
    },
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        // print the original value to the user
        return this.value + offset;
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d4fuLx6y/